# google play -how disable beta testing?

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app in google play. when I open the app in the store I see the label - "beta version". although I am posting a working version. to remove this mark, I need to disable beta testing. but I can't find it in the new console interface. any advice, I would be very grateful.

Comment: If you added your account to a testing track, you will see it say Beta version, however other people will not see this